# Android positioning ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I am too tired to figure this out, so pls help.

I have an image view in a RelativeLayout and i need to position it during run-time at the top of the screen and in the middle. (so top-middle). 
I figured out how to place it at the top:

```
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(obWidth, obHeight);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```

But now i only need to position in to the left a bit so it's in the middle of the screen.

BTW: I don't want to use margins.

Comment: have you tried to use linearlayout and attribute layout_gravity= center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: at last...thank you very much. Was looking for that "verb" for ages. *yawn* :)

Comment: Please accept the answser if it sovled your problem. Also, have you looked around at [Android SDK Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html) and more specifically in this case: [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)